# UOM Conversion in BOM ERPNext

Tags: erpnext, uomo

UOM conversion is not working in creation of BOM. For example, i have a raw material quantity .03 gram. Default raw material item UOM is in KG. When i try to insert the quantity in gram inside BOM, it does not convert. What can be the solution?

Comment: Isn't it possible to convert it programmatically before inserting to BOM?

Comment: From my end, not possible programmatically.